# Javascript new window form field error

Tags: javascript

I have created a new window and have fields that need to be completed, one a text field (for a numeric value) and the other is a radio button option (choose between 7 radio buttons). I can enter text and select a radio button but cannot obtain the value for the field id, e.g. myWindow.document.write ('Copies required: ') and for the button choice 
myWindow.document.write ('6x4 ').

How do I obtain the value for copies and tell if the radio button has been checked. Have displayed the value for copies and always says undefined. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you show your code

Answer (score 0):

How did you displayed the value?

In simple javascript it should be a code like:

```
alert(document.getElementById('IdofyourObject').value);
```

If you are using jQuery it would be:

```
alert($('#IdofyourObject').val());
```

Maybe you can share your code.

Comment: I did include the code in when i submitted my request, it looks like it has been removed when producing this request.

Comment: $(':text:first').focus();
myWindow.document.write ('<form action="#" form onsubmit="return false">');
myWindow.document.write ('<label>Copies required: <input type="text" name="copies" id="copies" value="0"></'+'label>');
myWindow.document.write ('<br>');
myWindow.document.write ('Print size required' + '<br>');
myWindow.document.write ('<label>6x4 £7<input type="radio" name="size" id="6x4" value="1"></'+'label>');
myWindow.document.write ('<br>' + '<label>7x5  £10<input type="radio" name="size" id="7x5" value="2"></'+'label>');
myWindow.document.write ('</'+'form>');
myWindow.focus();

   }